# Цикл while в какой-то момент начинает отнимать не то число, которое указано в теле js

Tags: javascript, циклы

Вроде бы очень простой цикл, не могу понять, почему так происходит. Заранее спасибо за объяснение.

```js
let cid = 0.5;

while (cid > 0) {
  cid -= 0.01;
  console.log(cid);
}
```

Comment: Оно даже вот так `0.1+0.2 === 0.3 // false`

Comment: Приложите код тектом

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что число хранится в памяти в бинарной форме, но дроби (в вашем случае 0,01) в двоичной системе счисления являются бесконечными. В JavaScript нет возможности для хранения точных значений 0.1 или 0.2, используя двоичную систему, точно также, как нет возможности хранить одну третью в десятичной системе счисления.
Подробнее можете почитать тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/number

Вы также можете исправить такое поведение переведя дробь в целое число, например, умножив на 100

```js
let cid = 0.5*100;

while (cid > 0) {
  cid -= 0.01*100;
  console.log(cid/100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Это происходит потому, что число хранится в памяти в бинарной форме, как последовательность бит – единиц и нулей. Но дроби на самом деле являются бесконечной дробью в двоичной форме.

Для того, что бы обойти проблему нужно округлить результат используя метод toFixed(n).

```html
let cid = 0.5;
while (cid > 0) {
  cid -= 0.01;
  console.log(cid.toFixed(2));
}
```